# SQL Server columns to support multilingual collation / characters

Tags: sql-server, internationalization, multilingual, collation, polish

I have a SQL Server database with default collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.
My table's columns are of `nvarchar` or `ntext` data type.

The database is to for a website which can be multilingual, must support at least Polish, English, later also Ukrainian and French.

I am even struggling to make it accept Polish characters. With columns of type `nvarchar/ntext`, I can manually change a string in the database to use Polish special characters but when using `insert` or `UPDATE` statements the special characters are stripped of their accents.

Eg.

```
INSERT INTO Some_Table 
VALUES( 7, 'aśęóń', 'ąćł', 0.1, 1)
```

this ends up being 'aseón' and 'acl' in the second and third columns on `INSERT` or `UPDATE` so loses original characters.

I have tried to set up different collation but even if the field has `Polish_CS_AS` it doesn't accept Polish chars on insert/ update.

How to make the database to accept different language characters?

Comment: You should use `VALUES( 7, N'aśęóń', N'ąćł', 0.1, 1)` (and also, you should stop using `ntext`, and use `nvarchar(max) instead)

Comment: Try prefixing with N to column while insert like `INSERT INTO Some_Table VALUES( 7, N'aśęóń',  N'ąćł', 0.1, 1)`

Comment: Thanks all, it work perfect now.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`INSERT INTO Some_Table VALUES( 7, N'aśęóń', N'ąćł', 0.1, 1)` if you have already set the corresponding column to `NVARCHAR` and the total number of values you tried to insert equal to what your table has since you did not specify which columns need to be inserted.